# Java Spring @autowire not working in test class

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I've a test class which autowires the CatalogDao class.  But the CatalogDao class is not autowired. The value is null;

Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PersistenceConfig.class})
public class CatalogDaoIT {

    @Autowired
    private CatalogDao catalogDao;
    
    @Test
    public void saveCatalog_readSame_foundOne() {
        // arrange
        Catalog catalog = new Catalog();
```

Config class

```
package ch.matica.platform.persistence.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ch.matica.platform.persistence")
public class PersistenceConfig {

        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesResolver() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }
}
```

The DAO class

```
package ch.matica.platform.persistence;

import java.util.Collection;
...

@Repository
public class CatalogDao {
...
```

Comment: Can you add CatalogDao to your question?

Comment: I added   @Import(CatalogDao.class)  , but still not working

Comment: You could do
@SpringBootTest 
public class CatalogDaoIT {

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your code to this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PersistenceConfig.class})
public class CatalogDaoIT {

@Autowired
private CatalogDao catalogDao;

//autowire by type, a private field and a setter
@Autowired
public void setCatalogDao(CatalogDao cd){
    this.catalogDao=cd;
}


@Test
public void saveCatalog_readSame_foundOne() {
    // arrange
    Catalog catalog = new Catalog();
```

I think this will help.

Comment: Still not working when adding    setCatalogDao(CatalogDao cd)

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked

```
@SpringBootTest 
public class CatalogDaoIT {
....
}
```

Comment: The application is not using  SpringBoot.   So, I can't use this annotation.

Comment: I noticed that have a wrong annotation in the test class :  @ContextConfiguration(classes = {PersistenceConfig.class})  .  This is for XML configurations.   I replaced it with  @Import({PersistenceConfig.class, CatalogDao.class}) , but it's still not working.